# How to check incoming requests in LiveServerTestCase?

Tags: javascript, django, selenium, django-forms

My use case:
I have a custom Django widget, that uses JavaScript, and I want to write a tests for it. I want to construct HTML with form that includes inputs rendered by the widget, then submit this form and do some checks on incoming POST request. I think it should be possible with Selenium and optionally [LiveServerTestCase](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.LiveServerTestCase).

But there are several problems:

1. Selenium does not allow to intercept such requests.
2. LiveServerTestCase runs server in separate thread, so I cant hook into view code and put asserts there.

How can I intercept requests coming from Selenium? Or maybe there are some other ways to test such things?

Answer (score 0):

The example from the Django docs you linked is the key. In the method `test_login` you'll see it does the GET request and then checks to see what all exists in the form.

```
def test_login(self):
    self.selenium.get('%s%s' % (self.live_server_url, '/login/'))
    username_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("username")
    username_input.send_keys('myuser')
    password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_name("password")
    password_input.send_keys('secret')
    self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@value="Log in"]').click()
```

You should follow the same path, but then make a post.

1. Do a `get` and check the content for the elements you want to see.
2. Populate the inputs with values that you need.
3. Do a `post`, and check the content for the elements you want to see.

Also, you mentioned javascript. You'll need to use `StaticLiveServerTestCase` in order to get the javascript to be served.